# Finding the largest number of spanning trees such a graph can have

Tags: graph-theory

If $G$ is a connected graph with $20$ vertices and $21$ edges, what is the largest number of spanning trees that $G$ can have?

There is [Cayley's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_formula) to solve this, but I am not too sure, as Cayley's formula needs the graph to be complete.

Comment: I might be incorrect but Cayley's theorem talks about groups and $S_{n}$. How does it help in a problem related to graph-theory?

Comment: @wrath  There is another Cayley’s theorem which counts how many distinct trees may span a (labelled) set of vertices.